# How to change prefix for alias at table with declarative base

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I got table like this:

```
class ReportImages(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'very_long_name_of_table'

    id = Column('long_column_name', Integer, primary_key=True)
```

And i run select from Oracle Database it raises exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00972: identifier is too long
[SQL: SELECT very_long_name_of_table.long_column_name AS very_long_name_of_table_long_column_name FROM very_long_name_of_table]
```

How can is set my own alias for select or not to use column aliases at all?

Select like

```
data = session.query(ReportImages).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with setting alias before query:

```
        ri = aliased(ReportImages, name='ri')
        data = session.query(ri)
```

It works, but still interesting how i can set label styling in ReportImages class.